# progress increase value not working well with percent

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/2gsNy/1/

I want make it +10, work for the 1st but the second and after it increase way than 10..

my js

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    $this = $('#progressbarr > div').width();
    var i = $this + 10;
    $('#progressbarr > div').css('width', (i + '%'));

    $progress_bar = $('#progressbarr');
    var progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * ($progress_bar.find('div').width()) / $progress_bar.width());
    $progress_bar.find('span').text(progressbar_width + '%');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use console.log() you can see that the width that you are using is not in percent but in pixel unit.

Try accessing the style attribute directly to retrieve the "xx%" value.

Comment: solved 

        $this = Math.floor (100 * ($('#progressbarr > div').width() / $('#progressbarr').width()) );
        var i = $this + 10;
        $('#progressbarr > div').css('width', (i + '%'));

thx

Answer (score 0):

Try the below [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/2gsNy/3/)

In Css, change

```
#progressbarr > div {
    background-color: green;
    width: 0px;
    height: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    $this = $('#progressbarr > div').width();
    var i = $this + 30;        

    $progress_bar = $('#progressbarr');
    var progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * (i) / $progress_bar.width());        

    if (progressbar_width <= 100)
    {
        $('#progressbarr > div').css('width', (i + 'px'));
        $progress_bar.find('span').text(progressbar_width + '%');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case this does work: [(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/2gsNy/6/)

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    $progress_bar = $('#progressbar');

    var i = 30;
    $('#progressbar > div').css('width', '+=' + (i + 'px'));


    var progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * ($progress_bar.find('div').width()) / $progress_bar.width());
    $progress_bar.find('span').text(progressbar_width + '%');
});
```

but only if you let your `progressbar` `width` on `300px`.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/2gsNy/7/

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    var width = $('#progressbarr > div').width();   
    var parentWidth = $('#progressbarr').width();
    var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
    console.log(percent);
    percent+=10;
    $('#progressbarr > div').width(percent+"%");
    $('#progressbarr > div').find('span').text(percent + '%');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gsNy/4/)

```
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    var progress = parseInt($(".percentage").html());
       $this = $('#progressbarr > div').width();
    var i = progress + 10;
    $('#progressbarr > div').css('width', (i + '%'));

    $progress_bar = $('#progressbarr');
    var progressbar_width = Math.floor(100 * ($progress_bar.find('div').width()) / $progress_bar.width());
    $progress_bar.find('span').text(progressbar_width + '%');

    // if
});
```